# Who will be shocked more?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuits

Will the elephant be shocked more as it has more cross section area?

Assuming they have the same conductivity.

[image]

Comment: Silly question.

Comment: Probably the elephant, on account of not understanding the concept of electricity. E seems to know exactly what he’s getting into.

Comment: @Pat There's a lot of people who would be equally "shocked" as the elephant in that case :)

Comment: There is a poor quality film of the deliberate electrocution of Topsy the elephant via application of 6,600VAC (Edison/USA), if that helps. I suspect elephant feet are pretty [insulating](https://i.imgur.com/0TOysNc.png), as seen in this tasteful umbrella stand, though the trunk tip would not be. Mr. E illustrates a series/parallel circuit.

Comment: This question cannot be answered factually with out more details.

Answer (score 3):

Try redrawing the diagram as an actual circuit diagram, replacing A through F with their equivalent resistance. Calculate the current through each element. Consider whether the elephant is more shocked seeing one person hold up two people by a single foot, or whether the people are more shocked to see an elephant on one foot.

Or, ask the instructor for help.

Answer (score 0):

A and F live the others die. C is connected in parallel to D and E is in series with the equivalent resistance of C ||D.

E and C||D are connected in parallel with the elephant. To find who is shocked more you have to find the area of contact of the elephant with the 220V supply line and contact area of C and D and E.